# How to create 1 view for 2 layouts in erb?

Tags: ruby, erb

I make a project on [serve](http://get-serve.com/) and use erb syntax.
I want to compile two files: index.html (compiled with template content) and load.html (only content). I create two layouts (_clear.html.erb (with the only yield) and _default.html.erb) and create a partial (_content_for_page.html.erb).

There are problems with compilation of index.html.erb.
According to [Rails manual](http://rusrails.ru/layouts-and-rendering-in-rails/structuring-layouts-2) (3.4.3 Partial Layouts) I have to write `index.html.erb`:

```
<%= render :partial => "_content_for_page.html.erb", :layout => "_default.html.erb" %>
```

But it doesn't work. Only partial is compiled.
What is wrong?

Comment: Can you post your code please.  Hard to figure out what is the problem without the code.

Answer (score 1):

First I just want to point out Serve does not utilize Rails unless the `rails` gem is included in the Gemfile of your project, but that will do something unexpected considering Serve organizes your project differently than Rails.

Now I don't know if this answers your question, but it may help to know partials should be rendered without the beginning underscore and are usually passed as a symbol.

```
<%= render :partial => :content_for_page, :layout => :default %>
```